# two buttons/links, one cllicked then change color till the other one is clicked. when the other one is clicked, do the same thing for that one

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want them to be like this.
one clicked, then change the color of that text to green untill the other one is clicked. when the other one clicked, then the clicked one turns to green and once clicked one goes back to the previous color. I tried that with css but it only does like active one. Can someone please help me

```
<div id="Space">
  <ul>
    <li role="presentation" class="sort">
      <a class="link" href="/?sort=score&page=1" style="text-decoration:none;">link1</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="date">
      <a class="link" href="/?sort=date&page=1"  style="text-decoration:none;">link2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: kindly show what you have tried so far

Comment: How about `$('a.link').on('click', function(e){ e.pre........ })` ?

Comment: @winixxee I have posted a answer let me know if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML Code:

```
<div id="Space">
<ul>
    <li role="presentation" class="sort">
      <a class="link1" href="/?sort=score&page=1" style="text-decoration:none;">link1</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="date">
      <a class="link2" href="/?sort=date&page=2"  style="text-decoration:none;">link2</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="date">
      <a class="link3" href="/?sort=date&page=3"  style="text-decoration:none;">link3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Jquery code:

```
//on page load
var ul_li_a = $("ul>li>a");
var lastClickTag = localStorage.getItem("last_clicked");

ul_li_a.css("color", "black");
if(lastClickTag){
  $("."+lastClickTag).css("color", "green")
}



$('ul>li').on("click", function(){      
  ul_li_a.css("color", "black");
  $(this).children("a").css("color", "green"); 
  localStorage.setItem("last_clicked", $(this).children("a").attr("class"));  
});
```

Please check the test code here: https://jsfiddle.net/kkm37zgd/2/

Comment: thanks but this kills the ability of a tag. when I click the link, it doesn't take me to that link.

Comment: maybe I misunderstand what you really want.
Please explain it a bit more..Once you click the link, what happen next?

Comment: sorry probably my fault for not making contexts clear, I'm trying to make it like this site; http://www.golfledger.com/ once I click following or new it changes background that link and stay like that till I click different one

Comment: meaning you want to do like, seeing if the link was clicked/visited already?

Comment: i updated the answer and the link for test code..kindly check it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105097/discussion-between-aldrien-h-and-winixxee).

Comment: sorry I just came bacck from washroom I'll try this thank you

Comment: Hello it does what the other answer does; it stays green till the page gets refreshed. as I click a link, untill it loads up it stays green but when the page gets refreshed then back to the original color

Comment: please check the updated code again. I made adjustments with your HTML code as well. Like changing class name.

Comment: this kills the links again

Comment: sorry @winixxee...i just forgot to removed the e.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a.link").on('click',function(){
   $(".link").css({"color":'whatever color you want'})
   $(this).css({'color':'blue'})
});
```

I think this shuld do

Comment: thank you but it says unexpected token at    $(.link).css({"color":'red'})

Comment: I forgot the double quotes try $(".link").css({"color':"red"})

Comment: yeah it does what I tried, when I click the link it works till it gets refreshed. when it finishes loading up and gets refreshed the color stays back where it should stay

Answer (score 0):

Posting a working snippet.

```js
$(function(){
 $('li[role="presentation"]').on('click',function(){
    $(this).closest('ul').find('.active').removeClass('active');       
    $(this).addClass('active');
 });
});
```

```css
.active a{  
  color:green;
}

a{
  font-color:black;
  font-size:24px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Space">
  <ul>
    <li role="presentation" class="sort">
      <a class="link" href="#">link1</a> 
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="date">
      <a class="link" href="#"  style="text-decoration:none;">link2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Note that I have removed the URL's from anchor tag just to avoid the navigation and show you the text color changes much better

Comment: What is not working? I see the snippet is doing what you asked for